# How do i fix my code for calculation when the output gives "NaN"?

Tags: java, jframe

I'm coding a SUVAT calculator (physics formula). It requires only 3 out of the 4 inputs. When I entered 3 values, the output gives NaN.

```
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    Output Ans = new Output();
    int n=0;//Initailize the n variable      

    {if (NumDis.getText().isEmpty()){//To count the number of input           
        n = n+1;
        }
    }
    {if (NumIni.getText().isEmpty()){           
        n = n+1;
        }
    }
    {if (NumFin.getText().isEmpty()){           
        n = n+1;
        }
    }       
    {if (NumTime.getText().isEmpty()){
        n = n+1;
    }
}
    Acceleration CallAccCal = new Acceleration();
    if(n == 1){//To Check if the number of input is 3
        CallAccCal.AccCal();//If yes, call the AccCal to calculate
        Ans.setVisible(true);//To make the Output class visible       
        }
else{
        Warning Warning = new Warning();
        Warning.setVisible(true);//If no, make the Warning class visible
}

}
double AccCal(){

    double Ini=0,Dis=0, Fin=0, Time=0, ans=0;

    if(!NumIni.getText().isEmpty()){
        Ini = Double.parseDouble(NumIni.getText());
            if(UUnit.isSelected()){ //To change the Unit
            Ini = Ini*1000;
            }
    }
    else{
        Ini=0;
    }
    if(!NumDis.getText().isEmpty()){
        Dis = Double.parseDouble(NumDis.getText());
            if(SUnit.isSelected()){
            Dis = Dis*1000;
    }
    }
    else{
        Dis=0;
    }
    if(!NumFin.getText().isEmpty()){
        Fin = Double.parseDouble(NumFin.getText());
        if(VUnit.isSelected()){
            Fin = Fin*1000;
            }
    }
    else{
        Fin=0;
    }
    if(!NumTime.getText().isEmpty()){
        Time = Double.parseDouble(NumTime.getText());
        if(TUnit.isSelected()){
            Time = Time*60;
            }
    }
    else{
        Time=0;
    }
        {
      if (NumDis.getText().isEmpty()){ 
          ans = (Fin-Ini)/Time;           
        }
      else if (NumFin.getText().isEmpty()){
          ans = 2*(Dis-(Ini*Time))/(Time*Time);
        }
      else if (NumIni.getText().isEmpty()){
          ans = 2*((Fin*Time)-Dis)/(Time*Time);
        }
      else if (NumTime.getText().isEmpty()){
          ans = ((Fin*Fin)-(Ini*Ini))/(2*Dis);
    }
        }
    return ans;

}

String format(double Ans){

    return String.format ("%.1f", Ans);}

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {   

    Acceleration AccAns = new Acceleration();
    double Answer = AccAns.AccCal();
    TextFieldAns.setText(format(Answer));}
```

Comment: You have four cases. Which case produces the NaN?

Comment: `if(n == 1){//To Check if the number of input is 3` this does not do what the comment says it does.

Comment: @Compass It does, if there are four inputs and you `n++` whenever one of those is _empty_. It's certainly not the most intuitive way, though.

Comment: It's not really possible for us to test and fix this code. From what I see, it looks valid (although a bit overly complicated), but I might be missing some typo, mismatched parens, or copy-paste error. Try to (a) print all the values before the calculation, and (b) move the actual calculation to a separate, testable method than can be used without all the UI stuff.

Comment: @tobias_k upon re-reading the code, you are correct, but the provided comment makes it very unintuitive.

Comment: Are you specifying zero in any of your text fields?  Dividing by zero never returns a finite number.

Comment: This code isn't enough to go on, for sure.  But it *looks* like you are never modifying the value of `Ans`.  When you have three inputs you just call `CallAccCal.AccCal()`, ignore the result - critically, not modifying `Ans` in any way - and then make `Ans` visible.  Thus I am not surprised that it's showing with its default value.  To fix this, you'll need to modify the Output's value in some way.

Comment: @tobias_k I tried printing the Ini value by initializing it to 1 ,and it printed 1.0. So i removed the if(!NumIni.getText().isEmpty()) condition and tried to run the program solely with Ini = Double.parseDouble(NumIni.getText());. However, it gave me error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you turning it into a String before you return it?

If so that's the issue.